# creating Dictionary-object from string that looks like dictionaries

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I have a string in that looks something similiar to the following:

```
myString = "major: 11, minor: 31, name: A=1,B=1,C=1,P=1, severity: 0, comment: this is down"
```

I have tried this so far:

```
dict(elem.split(':') for elem in myString.split(','))
```

It works fine until it catches the name-element above which can not be `split()` with `':'`.
Element in those format I would like to have as a new dictionary e.g.

```
myDic = {'major':'11', 'minor': '31', 'name':{'A':'1', 'B':'1', 'C':'1', 'P', '1'}, 'severity': '0', 'comment': 'this is down'}
```

If possible I would like to avoid complicated parsing as these turn out to be hard to maintain.
**Also I do not know the name/amount of the keys or values in the string above. I just know the format.** This is not a JSON-response, this is part of a text in a file and I have no control over the current format.

Comment: You'll need a custom parser for that format; the `,` in the `name` value is conflicting with the other commas in the string.

Comment: It certainly does not look like json, but if you have any control over the format, I do indeed suggest going with json.

Comment: @TomaszŁazarowicz you're right, I was looking at the dict :/

Comment: @TomaszŁazarowicz, this is indeed not JSON, and unfortunately I have no control over the format.

Comment: I suggest you either get a formal specification of the language you want to parse (the syntactic sugar isn't going to make that easy) or you switch to JSON which appears to have the same expressional power while coming with powerful, robust, lightweight tool support.

Comment: @theAlse If you cannot switch to JSON then ask for a formal specification for the notation, e.g. is the comma seperated list guaranteed to contain no whitespace, or just no whitespace before and after the comma, etc.

Comment: @ClassStacker, actually it is full of leading white-spaces but I should be able to remove those easily. The format with : and , is pretty much guaranteed.

Comment: Can a comma, colon or equal sign occur in the `comment` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another suggestion.

Why don't you transform it into a dictionary notation.

E.g. in a first step, you replace everything between a ':' and (comma or end of input) that contains a '=' (and mybe no whitespace, I don't know) by wrapping it in braces and replacing '=' by ':'.

In a second step, wrap everything between a ':' and (comma or end of input) in ', removing trailing and leading whitespace.

Finally, you wrap it all in braces.

I still don't trust that syntax, though... maybe after a few thousand lines have been processed successfully...

Answer (score 1):

FYI, This is NOT the complete solution ..

If this is the ***concrete structure*** of your input, and will be the constant pattern within your source, you can distinguish the **comma-separated** Tokens.

The difference between `major: 11`, and `name: A=1,B=1,C=1,P=1,` is that there is **SPACE** after the first token which makes the difference from the second token. So simply by adding a space into second `split` method, you can render your string properly.

So, the code should be something like this:

```
dict(elem.split(':') for elem in myString.split(', '))
```

Pay attention to send split method. There is a SPACE and comma ...

Regarding to the JSON format, it needs more work I guess. I have no idea now ..

Comment: I'd say it's pretty brave to interpret the given example in this way. It doesn't look like whoever invented this syntax had a clear vision of how this should be parsed, otherwise the syntax would be different. So how can we conclude that it follows these rules?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, I can not rely on white-spaces!

Answer (score 0):

At least, this parses the given example correctly...

```
import re

def parse(s):

    rx = r"""(?x)
        (\w+) \s* : \s*
        (
            (?: \w+ = \w+,)*
            (?: \w+ = \w+)
            |
            (?: [^,]+)
        )
    """

    r = {}
    for key, val in re.findall(rx, s):
        if '=' in val:
            val = dict(x.split('=') for x in val.split(','))
        r[key] = val
    return r


myString = "major: 11, minor: 31, name: A=1,B=1,C=1,P=1, severity: 0, comment: this is down"
print parse(myString)    
# {'comment': 'this is down', 'major': '11', 'name': {'A': '1', 'P': '1', 'C': '1', 'B': '1'}, 'minor': '31', 'severity': '0'}
```