# Create a dictionary with a string with colons

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

Let's say there's a string, s, which looks like this:

```
s = 'Title: A title Date: November 23 1234 Other: Other information'
```

Is it possible to create a dictionary which would be:

```
{'Title':'A title','Date':'November 23 1234','Other':'Other information'}
```

At first I thought simply by splitting it where the colons were, but then, not knowing what the values for Title could be, there may be colons in the title itself. Alas the source of this info doesn't separate it with commas as well, so that's also a pain. E.G, how could you also do it for:

```
s = 'Title: Example: of a title Date: November 23 1234 Other: Other information'
```

Where the title in that example is `Example: of a title`.

I've checked  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440940/creating-dictionary-object-from-string-that-looks-like-dictionaries), but it did not answer my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will there be any gap between the word preceding the colon and the colon itself? If not, you can use a custom regex to find those special tokens and split there.

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee There will not be. I'm not very experienced with regex (i.e, I know like nothing :p), and so I don't think I am able to do that myself.

Comment: Do you know the keys (e.g Title, Date, Other) in advance?

Comment: @root Yes <insert more characters>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
from itertools import izip

s = 'Title: Example: of a title Date: November 23 1234 Other: Other information'

keys = ['Title', 'Date', 'Other']
pattern = re.compile('({})\s+'.format(':|'.join(keys)))

print dict(izip(*[(i.strip() for i in (pattern.split(s)) if i)]*2))
```

out:

```
{'Date:': 'November 23 1234 ',
 'Other:': 'Other information',
 'Title:': 'Example: of a title '}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> s = 'Title: A title Date: November 23 1234 Other: Other information'
>>> matches = re.findall(r'(\w+): ((?:\w+\s)+)', s)
>>> 
>>> dict(matches)
    {'Date': 'November 23 1234 ', 'Other': 'Other ', 'Title': 'A title '}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but `Date` seems to be in the title value, and the value of Date seems to be left out

Comment: @Haidro: I guess it did disappear. There's probably a nicer way of doing it, but the regex works for your example.

Answer (score 0):

you can't just split it by colons, since there are multiples(possibly nested) of them.

if the keywords(`Title`, `Date`, `Other`) are fixed, you can try following regex:

```
import re
reg_ex = re.compile("Title\:(.+)Date\:(.+)Other\:(.+)")
reg_ex.match(s).groups() #(' A title ', ' November 23 1234 ', ' Other information')
```